# Converting T-SQL Left Join Subqueries to MS-Access

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ms-access, jet, data-conversion

I need help in converting this T-SQL query to MS ACCESS.  The error that I'm getting is JOIN expression not supported.

Update:

I can't add:

DDA ON TT.[Description] = DDA.AccountTypeDesc AND
       H.AccountNumber  = DDA.AccountNumber

But

DDA ON TT.[Description] = DDA.AccountTypeDesc

works.  Is there a way to add the second condition?

T-SQL Query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        [PesoAmount] = CASE WHEN FE.IsoCode IS NULL THEN
            LTRIM(STR(DFCF.CurrencyAmount, 20, 2))
        ELSE
            LTRIM(STR(DFCF.CurrencyAmount * FE.PhpConversionRate, 20, 2))
        END,
        DFCF.TransactionNumber,
        DFCF.AccountNumber,
        DFCF.CountryCd,
        DFCF.TransactionTypeCd,
        DFCF.Time,
        DFCF.Date,
        DFCF.TransactionStatusCd,
        DFCF.TransactionCurrencyCd,
        DFCF.BranchNumber,
        DFCF.RemitterExtPartyCd,
        DFCF.BeneficiaryExtPartyCd,
        DFCF.PostedDate,
        DFCF.AssociateNumber,
        DFCF.ExecutingPartyNumber,
        DFCF.CurrencyAmount,
        DFCF.CurrencyAmountInTxnCcy,
        DFCF.CurrencyAmountInAccountCcy,
        DFCF.SecondaryAccountKey,
        DFCF.RelatedInd,
        DFCF.ThirdPartyInd,
        DFCF.TransactionDescription,
        DFCF.SecurityName,
        DFCF.DealNumber
    FROM
        dbo.DesFactCashFlow DFCF (NOLOCK)                                            LEFT JOIN
        dbo.ForeignExchange   FE (NOLOCK) ON DFCF.TransactionCurrencyCd = FE.IsoCode
)
                           H                                                                                          LEFT JOIN
    dbo.Ctr                C (NOLOCK) ON H.PesoAmount                           = C.PesoAmountFaceValueSumInsured AND
                                         H.AccountNumber                        = C.AccountNumber                 AND
                                         H.TransactionTypeCd                    = C.TransactionType                   LEFT JOIN
    dbo.TransactionType   TT (NOLOCK) ON H.TransactionTypeCd                    = TT.Code                             LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT
        [AccountNumber]               = DDA2.AccountNumber,
        [AccountTypeDesc]             = DDA2.AccountTypeDesc,
        [LineOfBusinessName]          = MAX(DDA2.LineOfBusinessName),
        [AccountCurrencyCode]         = MAX(DDA2.AccountCurrencyCode),
        [AccountCurrencyName]         = MAX(DDA2.AccountCurrencyName),
        [AccountRegistrationTypeDesc] = MAX(DDA2.AccountRegistrationTypeDesc),
        [AccountRegistrationName]     = MAX(DDA2.AccountRegistrationName),
        [AccountName]                 = MAX(DDA2.AccountName),
        [AlternateName]               = MAX(DDA2.AlternateName),
        [AccountOpenDate]             = MAX(DDA2.AccountOpenDate),
        [AccountCloseDate]            = MAX(DDA2.AccountCloseDate),
        [AccountStatusDesc]           = MAX(DDA2.AccountStatusDesc),
        [DormantInd]                  = MAX(DDA2.DormantInd),
        [ProductLineName]             = MAX(DDA2.ProductLineName),
        [ProductCategoryName]         = MAX(DDA2.ProductCategoryName),
        [ProductTypeName]             = MAX(DDA2.ProductTypeName),
        [ProductName]                 = MAX(DDA2.ProductName),
        [ProductNumber]               = MAX(DDA2.ProductNumber),
        [AccountTaxId]                = MAX(DDA2.AccountTaxId),
        [AccountTaxIdTypeCode]        = MAX(DDA2.AccountTaxIdTypeCode),
        [AccountTaxStateCode]         = MAX(DDA2.AccountTaxStateCode),
        [AccountPrimaryBranchName]    = MAX(DDA2.AccountPrimaryBranchName),
        [MailingAddress1]             = MAX(DDA2.MailingAddress1),
        [MailingAddress2]             = MAX(DDA2.MailingAddress2),
        [MailingCityName]             = MAX(DDA2.MailingCityName),
        [MailingStateCode]            = MAX(DDA2.MailingStateCode),
        [MailingStateName]            = MAX(DDA2.MailingStateName),
        [MailingPostalCode]           = MAX(DDA2.MailingPostalCode),
        [MailingCountryCode]          = MAX(DDA2.MailingCountryCode),
        [MailingCountryName]          = MAX(DDA2.MailingCountryName),
        [CurrencyBasedAccountInd]     = MAX(DDA2.CurrencyBasedAccountInd),
        [MaturityDate]                = MAX(DDA2.MaturityDate),
        [OriginalLoanAmount]          = MAX(DDA2.OriginalLoanAmount),
        [CollateralTypeDesc]          = MAX(DDA2.CollateralTypeDesc),
        [CollateralTypeCode]          = MAX(DDA2.CollateralTypeCode),
        [InsuredAmount]               = MAX(DDA2.InsuredAmount),
        [EmployeeInd]                 = MAX(DDA2.EmployeeInd)
    FROM
        dbo.DesDimAccount DDA2 (NOLOCK)
    GROUP BY
        DDA2.AccountNumber,
        DDA2.AccountTypeDesc
)
                         DDA          ON RTRIM(TT.[Description])                = RTRIM(DDA.AccountTypeDesc)      AND
                                         H.AccountNumber                        = DDA.AccountNumber
```

EDIT: I replaced the query with the AS keyword.  I get the same error.
MS Access Query with Error:

```
SELECT
    'H'                           AS [HeaderRecordIndicator],
    '1'                           AS [SupervisingAgency],
    '0' + I.InstitutionCode       AS [InstitutionCode],
    CONVERT(char(8), H.Date, 112) AS [ReportDate],
    'CTR'                         AS [ReportType],
    '21'                          AS [FormatCode],
    '1'                           AS [SubmissionType]
FROM
(((
    SELECT
        IIF(ISNULL(FE.IsoCode), FORMAT(DFCF.CurrencyAmount, "##################.00"), FORMAT(DFCF.CurrencyAmount * FE.PhpConversionRate, "##################.00")) AS [PesoAmount],
        DFCF.TransactionNumber,
        DFCF.AccountNumber,
        DFCF.CountryCd,
        DFCF.TransactionTypeCd,
        DFCF.Time,
        DFCF.Date,
        DFCF.TransactionStatusCd,
        DFCF.TransactionCurrencyCd,
        DFCF.BranchNumber,
        DFCF.RemitterExtPartyCd,
        DFCF.BeneficiaryExtPartyCd,
        DFCF.PostedDate,
        DFCF.AssociateNumber,
        DFCF.ExecutingPartyNumber,
        DFCF.CurrencyAmount,
        DFCF.CurrencyAmountInTxnCcy,
        DFCF.CurrencyAmountInAccountCcy,
        DFCF.SecondaryAccountKey,
        DFCF.RelatedInd,
        DFCF.ThirdPartyInd,
        DFCF.TransactionDescription,
        DFCF.SecurityName,
        DFCF.DealNumber
    FROM
        DesFactCashFlow DFCF                                            LEFT JOIN
        ForeignExchange   FE ON DFCF.TransactionCurrencyCd = FE.IsoCode
) AS
                       H                                                                                 LEFT JOIN
    Ctr                C ON H.PesoAmount                           = C.PesoAmountFaceValueSumInsured AND
                            H.AccountNumber                        = C.AccountNumber                 AND
                            H.TransactionTypeCd                    = C.TransactionType)                   LEFT JOIN
    TransactionType   TT ON H.TransactionTypeCd                    = TT.Code)                             LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT
        DDA2.AccountNumber                    AS [AccountNumber],
        DDA2.AccountTypeDesc                  AS [AccountTypeDesc],
        MAX(DDA2.LineOfBusinessName)          AS [LineOfBusinessName],
        MAX(DDA2.AccountCurrencyCode)         AS [AccountCurrencyCode],
        MAX(DDA2.AccountCurrencyName)         AS [AccountCurrencyName],
        MAX(DDA2.AccountRegistrationTypeDesc) AS [AccountRegistrationTypeDesc],
        MAX(DDA2.AccountRegistrationName)     AS [AccountRegistrationName],
        MAX(DDA2.AccountName)                 AS [AccountName],
        MAX(DDA2.AlternateName)               AS [AlternateName],
        MAX(DDA2.AccountOpenDate)             AS [AccountOpenDate],
        MAX(DDA2.AccountCloseDate)            AS [AccountCloseDate],
        MAX(DDA2.AccountStatusDesc)           AS [AccountStatusDesc],
        MAX(DDA2.DormantInd)                  AS [DormantInd],
        MAX(DDA2.ProductLineName)             AS [ProductLineName],
        MAX(DDA2.ProductCategoryName)         AS [ProductCategoryName],
        MAX(DDA2.ProductTypeName)             AS [ProductTypeName],
        MAX(DDA2.ProductName)                 AS [ProductName],
        MAX(DDA2.ProductNumber)               AS [ProductNumber],
        MAX(DDA2.AccountTaxId)                AS [AccountTaxId],
        MAX(DDA2.AccountTaxIdTypeCode)        AS [AccountTaxIdTypeCode],
        MAX(DDA2.AccountTaxStateCode)         AS [AccountTaxStateCode],
        MAX(DDA2.AccountPrimaryBranchName)    AS [AccountPrimaryBranchName],
        MAX(DDA2.MailingAddress1)             AS [MailingAddress1],
        MAX(DDA2.MailingAddress2)             AS [MailingAddress2],
        MAX(DDA2.MailingCityName)             AS [MailingCityName],
        MAX(DDA2.MailingStateCode)            AS [MailingStateCode],
        MAX(DDA2.MailingStateName)            AS [MailingStateName],
        MAX(DDA2.MailingPostalCode)           AS [MailingPostalCode],
        MAX(DDA2.MailingCountryCode)          AS [MailingCountryCode],
        MAX(DDA2.MailingCountryName)          AS [MailingCountryName],
        MAX(DDA2.CurrencyBasedAccountInd)     AS [CurrencyBasedAccountInd],
        MAX(DDA2.MaturityDate)                AS [MaturityDate],
        MAX(DDA2.OriginalLoanAmount)          AS [OriginalLoanAmount],
        MAX(DDA2.CollateralTypeDesc)          AS [CollateralTypeDesc],
        MAX(DDA2.CollateralTypeCode)          AS [CollateralTypeCode],
        MAX(DDA2.InsuredAmount)               AS [InsuredAmount],
        MAX(DDA2.EmployeeInd)                 AS [EmployeeInd]
    FROM
        DesDimAccount DDA2
    GROUP BY
        DDA2.AccountNumber,
        DDA2.AccountTypeDesc
) AS
                         DDA          ON RTRIM(TT.[Description])                = RTRIM(DDA.AccountTypeDesc)      AND
                                         H.AccountNumber                        = DDA.AccountNumber
```

Here is the simplified query with the same error:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
(((
    SELECT
        IIF(ISNULL(FE.IsoCode), FORMAT(DFCF.CurrencyAmount, "##################.00"), FORMAT(DFCF.CurrencyAmount * FE.PhpConversionRate, "##################.00")) AS [PesoAmount],
        DFCF.TransactionNumber,
        DFCF.TransactionCurrencyCd,
    FROM
        DesFactCashFlow DFCF                                            LEFT JOIN
        ForeignExchange   FE ON DFCF.TransactionCurrencyCd = FE.IsoCode
) AS
                       H                                                                                 LEFT JOIN
    Ctr                C ON H.PesoAmount                           = C.PesoAmountFaceValueSumInsured AND
                            H.AccountNumber                        = C.AccountNumber                 AND
                            H.TransactionTypeCd                    = C.TransactionType)                   LEFT JOIN
    TransactionType   TT ON H.TransactionTypeCd                    = TT.Code)                             LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT
        DDA2.AccountNumber                    AS [AccountNumber],
        DDA2.AccountTypeDesc                  AS [AccountTypeDesc],
        MAX(DDA2.LineOfBusinessName)          AS [LineOfBusinessName],
    FROM
        DesDimAccount DDA2
    GROUP BY
        DDA2.AccountNumber,
        DDA2.AccountTypeDesc
) AS
                         DDA          ON RTRIM(TT.[Description])                = RTRIM(DDA.AccountTypeDesc)      AND
                                         H.AccountNumber                        = DDA.AccountNumber
```

Comment: As far as I remember you ought to write `AS` before an alias.

Comment: Updated, but it returns the same error even if I use the AS keyword

Comment: Try to use `AS` for table aliases too. I don't see any problems with `JOIN`'s

Comment: Hi Igor, where specifically on my query.  As far as I know I used aliases on all tables and it has an error.  Can you provide the correct query?  Or can you provide joins with subqueries?

Comment: How are you attempting to run that query when you get the error?  From the Access query designer or some other method?

Comment: Hi HansUp, yes I'm running it in the Access Query Desinger

Comment: Ok HansUp, I trimmed down my query may I know where the error is?

Comment: I suspect it is due the last `ON` clause --- but not because it includes a function.  I think you run into trouble when your left join refers to fields to the right of the left-most data source.  I don't know if that make sense, so build the joins in the query designer and see for yourself.

Comment: Why do you need to convert the query? Is SQL Server no longer available to you? If it is available, there may be other ways around using this with MS Access.

Comment: Yes SQL Server is no longer available

Comment: Update:

I can't add:

DDA ON TT.[Description] = DDA.AccountTypeDesc AND
       H.AccountNumber  = DDA.AccountNumber

But

DDA ON TT.[Description] = DDA.AccountTypeDesc

works.  Is there a way to add the second condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give up trying to *convert* the SQL text from your T-SQL query to Access SQL.  Create a new Access query from scratch and use the T-SQL query only as a road map.  Add your data sources and set up the joins.  The query designer will guarantee you create the joins in the manner which keeps the db engine happy: addition and positioning of parentheses it requires for queries with more than one join; the rules which apply for LEFT JOINs; and so forth.  Just let the designer handle those details for you.

The designer will choke in Design View due to the functions in this part of your last join:

```
RTRIM(TT.[Description]) = RTRIM(DDA.AccountTypeDesc)
```

So leave out the `RTRIM()` functions while you're setting up the joins in Design View.  Don't worry that the query doesn't return the correct results.  After you get joins which satisfy the db engine, switch to SQL View and add the `RTRIM()` functions back in.

After you get the joins set up correctly, then add in your field expressions to the `SELECT` list.

Also you may find it easier to manage your complex query by breaking out the subqueries as separate saved queries --- then reference those queries by name in the master query just as you would table sources.

Comment: Update:

I can't add:

DDA ON TT.[Description] = DDA.AccountTypeDesc AND
       H.AccountNumber  = DDA.AccountNumber

But

DDA ON TT.[Description] = DDA.AccountTypeDesc

works.  Is there a way to add the second condition?

Comment: If you can't find a way to make the join work with AccountNumber in the `ON` clause, move it to a final `WHERE` clause: `WHERE H.AccountNumber = DDA.AccountNumber` You may need to add `OR DDA.AccountNumber Is Null`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the penultimate line:

```
  DDA ON RTRIM(TT.[Description]) = RTRIM(DDA.AccountTypeDesc) AND
```

The Design View of the Access query designer can't work with functions in the `ON` part of the clause. You must remove the `RTRIM`.

Comment: @HansUp: You're absolutely right. Corrected. I was mixing this up with constants not being allowed (like:  `... ON TT.Description = '123'`).

Comment: Update:

I can't add:

DDA ON TT.[Description] = DDA.AccountTypeDesc AND
       H.AccountNumber  = DDA.AccountNumber

But

DDA ON TT.[Description] = DDA.AccountTypeDesc

works.  Is there a way to add the second condition?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of MSAccess you are using in your system? I just tried in 2007 version and RTRIM is working.

Comment: We're using the same version: 2007!

Answer (score 0):

Access is parenthesis happy. Wrap each join expression in parentheses, the ON clauses themselves, and each pair of tables.

You can't use CONVERT, NOLOCK, or CASE.